# Estimating variances components for a 2-way structure with all factors random using r

Tags: r

My data is a balanced 2-way structure with weight as the response, and day and operator as the random factors. I want to obtain the estimates of the variance components for the main effects and the 2-factor interaction. I have tried using the function lmer in r, where I can include the main effects, i.e. lmer(weight~(1|dia)+(1|opdr), data=balz), but I cannot find a way to include the interaction.
Thank you for your help. JC

Answer (score 0):

The lmer does not accept the specification of the model as 1|A*B or as 1|A + 1|B + 1|A*B.  I obtained the desired results specifying the model as 1|A + 1|B + 1|A:B.
JCF